The reference node
I want to calculate currents of resistors by choosing the referance node A and B. Could you help me to solve this problem?


The answer to that is "yes". But the problem is, we don't need what help you need to solve it so we can't provide a real answer. You need to edit in a specific question what help you need and then someone can answer it.

Thevenin equivalents Vth do not need a reference.

physicsae, There's a tag called "nodal analysis" that is attached to your question. You don't write much. But are you looking, specifically, for the application of nodal analysis to this problem? If so, that would justify the use of a ground referenced node. (Other methods don't require it. But nodal does require it because of the rank-nullity theorem.) If you are looking for other methods, such as Norton-Thevenin or mesh, then a single ground reference isn't necessary though for mesh you do start with 0 V somewhere and then work yourself around a loop.)

Hint
Just by visual inspection I can see that the current through the 6 Ω resistor is 2 amps. I'm giving you that answer directly so you know that it is dead-easy to solve without calculator, pen or paper. Now you should use your noggin. Hint: I converted the current sources and their respective parallel resistors to voltage sources in series with a resistor.

A reference node is a Ground node assumed to be at zero potential. One simple way to choose a reference node is to look for a node with maximum number of branches or maximum number of lines connected to it. There is only one reference node unless there is a supernode  in which two nodes are linked. Since forming a supernode or supermesh is not required in the circuit, Any of A, B or C can be a reference node.
Another point is to choose a reference node based on any other rules to make the circuit analysis easier such as not having to form supernodes or supermesh etc during analysis. In the above circuit, C is a good candidate for a reference node compared to A and B although A and B can also be reference nodes.
When using nodal analysis, there are two nodal voltages at A and B with C at ground which can be used to find currents in all resistors.
When using mesh analysis, choosing reference node is not necessary.
